# How to change position of symbols that are moved by transposition sign in equation?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, equations, positioning

I have equation

```
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}(k+1|k) = \textbf{F}(k)\textbf{P}(k|k)\textbf{F}^T(k) + \textbf{Q}(k)
\end{align}
```

where the sign of transposition `\textbf{F}^T` makes second the time symbol `(k)` goes much more from matrix `\textbf{F}`. How to make it closer? Ideally `\textbf{F}` and `(k)` should be in same distance in case of `\textbf{F}(k)` and `\textbf{F}^T(k)`.

Comment: An obligatory read :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: Changed to align.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just insert `\!`, which gives you a small "negative" horizontal space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\textbf{P}(k+1|k) = \textbf{F}(k)\textbf{P}(k|k)\textbf{F}^T\!(k) + \textbf{Q}(k)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

By the way, the `eqnarray` environment is deprecated nowadays. For this use, I think `equation` would serve you well.

Comment: I would also suggest making a macro for the `|`. `|` are used for so many different things, which makes it a nightmare to distinguish each usage from each other.

Comment: In this document x(k|k-1) means value of x conditional by prediction from k-1 step and x(k|k) means value of x conditional by measurement in time step k.